I have a problem finding element using SELENIUM
I'm trying to find an element which is quite deep inside the HTML, and I have try Xpath, class, link text and css methods and any of those work. I always get the same error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException.
Here I send the HTML:
enter image description here
The last thing I've tried is this:
selector = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/nav/section[2]/ul/li[4]/a[@class="mega-menu__link"]')
        selector.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        selector.click()
        time.sleep(5)


[ask] and [mre]

Edit your question and put the HTML in the form of text not image. Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

Without seeing the page it's hard to say for sure what the issue is but it's likely 1 or 2 things...

The locator may be incorrect. I would try
CSS selectors
a[href*='upcoming.html']
a.mega-menu__link

XPath
a[text()='Upcoming']


Add a wait to make sure the page has finished loading before searching for the element
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

...

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='upcoming.html']"))).click()



